# nginx multiple servers with catchall always triggering catchall

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, https, redirect

I want to host 2 sites on 1 server (to save money, my server is only using like 2% CPU at any time anyway). I ran into an issue a month ago where google shows my IP instead of domain in search results, so I added a catchall redirect. When I try hosting my example2.com, the catchall always triggers and redirects to example1.com.

example1.com is more important; example2.com is more of a side project, so I want the catchall to go to example1.com. The problem is that example2.com (http and https) is also being redirected to example1.com.

```
# Catchall configuration - redir to the domain for bare and invalid domain requests
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    return 301 https://example1.com$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS for example1.com
server {
  listen       443 ssl;
  server_name  example1.com;

  ssl_certificate  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/privkey.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}

# example2
server {
    listen 80 ;
    server_name example2.com www.example2.com;

    return 301 https://example2.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example2.com www.example2.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the output of `nginx -T`.

Comment: its really long but this is the right output file (it says "# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:" and the contents match)